# Wordpress - migrating posts and images only

Tags: wordpress, import, importerror

I am changing my Wordpress theme. I've set it up on a development server. I now want to import the posts, pages and media to populate the database.

I have been using the built-in Wordpress import/export function which is erratic when it comes to media. Sometimes all the imports fail, sometimes some of them fail. It's problematic and I am giving up on that.

Is there a reliable plugin that I can use? I've been searching without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried all types of plugins as well as WP built-in export/import functions. The solution that worked well for me was All-in-One Migration plus All-in-One Migration Extension so allow the transfer of 16GB of data. I've had one or two hiccups along the way but the technical support folks at ServMask are very responsive and solved the issues expeditiously.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to create a dev environment for wordpress is to create a mirror copy of it and then changing its url.

You would need to copy over all the files and restore the database on the dev environment and then hard coding your dev url in wp-config.php. At that point, you can upload the new theme and activate it.

Comment: The current WP version is 39 updates behind. Won't that create a problem if I clone it?

Comment: You're cloning a copy of it, it shouldnt cause an issue because you'll also be cloning all the wordpress files.